# Finding the extraposed subject in "It is plain to see that you don't like dogs."

Tags: subjects, dummy-it

> *It is plain to see that you don't like dogs.*

Here, what does *it* refer to?
*To see that you don't like dogs* or *that you don't like dogs*?

If it refers to the former, then the sentence means:

> *To see that you don't like dogs is plain.*

If the latter, then it means:

> *That you don't like dogs is plain to see.*

Since both do make sense at least semantically, I wonder what would be the better syntactic analysis of the sentence. Or whether either would be an equally possible analysis.

Also, would your answer change if

(1) *plain* was replaced with *easy* in the original sentence?

(2) *to see* was replaced with *seeing* in the original sentence?

### EDIT

Eight years later, I'd like to revisit this question. Back then, this question received two answers saying that it is *that you don't like dogs* that is the extraposed subject, not *to see that you don't like dogs*, perhaps the reason being *That you don't like dogs is plain to see* sounds more idiomatic than does *To see that you don't like dogs is plain*.

Then, what if we change *plain* to *possible*?

> *It is possible to see that you don't like dogs.*

Here, I think it's virtually impossible to say *That you don't like dogs is possible to see*, and the only option left is to say *To see that you don't like dogs is possible*. Does this mean that the extraposed subject in the new sentence is not *that you don't like dogs* but *to see that you don't like dogs*?

If so, is it okay for the extraposed subject to be changed in the virtually the same construction?

Comment: "plain to see" is an idiomatic expression and cannot be broken down like this. Okay, an analogous structure without such an idiomatic expression or set phrase may still pose the same question, but I seriously doubt it.

Comment: @Kris- Why do you say it's idiomatic and can't be broken down.  If something is plain - it is clear. So *plain* means plain and *to see* means to see, so I'd think it can be understood word for word- no idioms required.

Comment: Can you say _That you don't like dogs is possible to see_? Can you say _That it's 4 pm is possible to see?_ Yes, in certain circumstances: _It's possible to see that it's 4 pm by watching the shadow there_

Comment: @JohnLawler Are you saying that _That you don't like dogs is possible to see_ is not an odd thing to say?

Comment: @JK2 It certainly improves with extraposition. I wouldn't say it, because it isn't clear what it means and why the circumlocution was chosen; also I'd pick different lexical items. But who knows what others might say?

Comment: @JohnLawler But you would be able to say _That you don't like dogs is plain to see_, wouldn't you?

Comment: It's grammatical, but  odd because the norm is to extrapose, and one has to wonder about why the heavy subject was left there. As for the first sentence you asked about, I think there are some problems with unextraposed _S be possible to see_ clauses. I'd star *_That you don't like dogs is possible to see_; I think it's a problem with the lexical item "possible", which  is an extremely odd adjective syntactically, even for a modal.

Comment: As mentioned in an answer, *plain to see* is one unit. It can be substituted with the adjective *obvious*. *That you don't like dogs is obvious.* *Possible to see* doesn't work like that.

Comment: @TinfoilHat So, it's okay to have different analyses for virtually the same construction, depending on the lexical properties of the adjective?

Comment: I’m having a hard time accepting *It’s possible to see that...* (let alone how you want to un-extrapose it) as the least bit idiomatic.  Even if you accept @JohnLawler ’s stretch — *That it’s 4 pm is possible to see by watching the shadow there.* — what would you make of *That it’s 4 pm is likely to see by watching the shadow there.*?

Comment: @TinfoilHat I can find at least three instances of _It’s possible to see that..._ in the New York Times: 1. _In retrospect, though, it's possible to see that Bey was part of a more..._ 2. _Looking at Lange's career today, it's possible to see that her photographic innovations were less visual..._ 3. _Thanks to the panel data, it's possible to see that much of the..._

Comment: @JK2 Yes, and in each example they mean _one can see_, with a presupposed _now_. And each one is extraposed. Can you say them unextraposed? _Looking at Lange's career today, that her photographic innovations were less visual ... is possible to see._

Comment: Based on your examples from the NY Times, where *possible* is used in the sense of ability, your dog sentence is missing something then. *Now that my glasses are adjusted, it is possible [I am able] to see that you don't like dogs.* <-- *Now that your glasses are adjusted, what is possible?* --> *Now that my glasses are adjusted, to see that you don't like dogs is possible.* // *\*Now that your glasses are adjusted, what is possible to see?* ∴ *\*Now that my glasses are adjusted, that you don't like dogs is possible to see.*

Comment: @JohnLawler I don't know why you're asking the obvious, given that you've already noticed the "problem with the lexical item _possible_." And no, I can never "say them unextraposed." ?? _Looking at Lange's career today, that her photographic innovations were less visual ... is possible to see._

Comment: @TinfoilHat I think _see_ in _It is possible to see that you don't like dogs_ means "understand" rather than "use the power of sight", just as does _see_ in _Can't you see that she's taking advantage of you?_.

Comment: That doesn't matter. Try: *Thanks to the panel data, it is possible [I am able] to see [understand] that you don't like dogs.*

Comment: @TinfoilHat Do you mean that in _It is possible to see that you don't like dogs_, the adjective _possible_ cannot be used in the sense of ability?

Comment: Yes. With no further context/discourse, the *possible* in the standalone sentence *It is possible to see that you don't like dogs* is the *possible* of likelihood, not of ability.

Comment: @TinfoilHat How do you know when there's no context at all? If there's no context, shouldn't the interpretation be open to both "likelihood" and "ability"? Moreover, why should _possible_ have to mean "ability" in order for the sentence to work?

Comment: Let's back it up... Try this: *It is possible to see dogs.* *To see dogs is possible.* *\*Dogs are possible to see* (incorrect/unidiomatic). *Plain to see* is an idiom that functions as an adjective. *\*It is plain to see dogs.* *\*It is obvious dogs.* You can't compare *possible to see* and *plain to see*.

Comment: @TinfoilHat Sorry, but that's not "backing it up". When the object of _see_ is _dogs_ (instead of _that you don't like dogs_), _see_ can only mean "use the power of sight", which doesn't work well with the adjective _plain_. So, you're right about your assessment of your own _dogs_ examples, but that shouldn't tell you anything about the _that_-clause examples in the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Since the sentence can be reduced to:

> It is plain to see.

Whatever *it* refers to is plain to see, and what is plain to see in your sentence is that you don't like dogs.

Therefore the the proper parse is your second option:

> That you don't like dogs is plain to see.

Changing *plain* to *easy* does not affect the result:

> That you don't like dogs is easy to see.

Changing to *seeing* results in a completely new sentence:

> It is plain seeing that you don't like dogs.

I would parse this as:

> <sub><sup>*< Something from previous context >*</sup></sub> is obvious <sub><sup>(clear/apparent)</sup></sub> since we can see that you don't like dogs.

Comment: So "To see that you don't like dogs is plain" is comparable in structure to "It is plain seeing that you don't like dogs."?

Comment: No, I'd say they are different.  "*To see that you don't like dogs is plain*" is comparable to "*It is plain to see that you don't like dogs*"   When you use *seeing* the way you are here, *seeing* becomes equivalent to *on account of* or *in view of* and may be an elided form of "*in seeing that*" or some people use it with *as*:  "*Seeing as* you don't like chocolate, I've given you the strawberry."  (*In view of the fact that you don't like chocolate, I've given you the strawberry*.)

Comment: How about this sentence? _It is possible to see that you don't like dogs._ What does _it_ refer to? Does _it_ refer to _that you don't like dogs_? Or this time, does _it_ refer to _to see that you don't like dogs_?

Answer (score 1):

*It is plain to see* is a "semantic unit" that means, essentially, *clearly*:

> *Clearly* you don't like dogs.